# How to correctly export time&dates from excel using python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, xlrd

I am trying to create a time-plot and therefore I have to use date-data from excel. The data is in the first column of my excelsheet and therefore I use the following code:

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

#Define xlsfiles
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("workbookname.xlsx")
sheet = wb_octopus.sheet_by_name("nameofsheet")

#Read data from excelsheet
Y1_data = np.array(sheet.col_values(8, start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None))
Y2_data = np.array(sheet.col_values(11, start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None))
for i in range(len(Y1_data)):
     date_data = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(i,0).value,1)
     time_data.append(date_data)
```

The problem is that the dates are wrongly interpreted by python as my first date in excel is 2-12-2011  3:05:00 and python gives `datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 3, 3, 5`).

I hope someone is able to explain why this is happening and how I can solve it.

Comment: Why is my question -1?

Comment: It seems your asking 3 questions here instead of one. Also it's not reproducible, see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

[xlrd's documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html) talks a bit about issues that occur from Excel's method for storing dates - specifically from Spreadsheets that are created on Mac. With this, you may be able to determine a timedelta that would need to be added to each date.

Another option would be to open the Spreadsheet in Excel and copy and paste the date column as text. That way, it would be interpreted as a string by xlrd which could then be formatted as a datetime object.

Comment: I found a solution in the xlrd documentation. The last option (copy and paste the date column as text) did not work for me. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the documentation shared by chrisheinze, I found out that the problem was in the following line in my code:

```
date_data = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(i,0).value,1)
```

It seems that the 1 at the end specifies a Macintosh datetime conversion, which states that the first day in the date system is 1904-01-02. I am not working on a mac so I had to change this to a 1900-based datemode and therefore had to change the line as follows:

```
date_data = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(i,0).value,0)
```

This solved my issues.